# does weblogic 12C support native toplink

Tags: jpa, weblogic, eclipselink, native, toplink

from 11G, weblogic use ecliplselink  as it's default jpa solution, anyone can tell me is native toplink is still be supported in weblogic 12c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, TopLink is still supported, [certified](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/toplink/documentation/weblogic-086699.html) and is considered the default provider in WLS, but what version do you mean and what API are you using?

You might want to checkout the TopLink [datasheet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/toplink/toplink-datasheet-2222722.pdf) and [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/toplink/documentation/index.html) though, as EclipseLink provides the core persistence used underneath TopLink.